# Why does a pandas dataframe with sparse columns take up more memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataset with mixed sparse / dense columns. As the number of sparse columns greatly outnumber the number of dense I wanted to see if I could store these in an efficient manner using [sparse data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html) in pandas. However, while testing the functionality I found dataframes with sparse columns appear to take up more memory, consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.zeros(10000000)
b = np.zeros(10000000)
a[3000:3100] = 2
b[300:310] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.SparseArray(a), 'b':pd.SparseArray(b)})
print(df.info())
```

This prints `memory usage: 228.9 MB`.
Next:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
print(df.info())
```

This prints `memory usage: 152.6 MB`.

Does the non-sparse dataframe take up less space? Am I misunderstanding?

Installation info:

- pandas 0.25.0
- python 3.7.2

Comment: Can't reproduce this- on my system both have 152.6 MB

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've reproduced those exact numbers. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.SparseArray.html):

> Pandas provides data structures for efficiently storing sparse data.
>   These are not necessarily sparse in the typical “mostly 0”. Rather,
>   you can view these objects as being “compressed” where any data
>   matching a specific value (NaN / missing value, though any value can
>   be chosen, including 0) is omitted. The compressed values are not
>   actually stored in the array.

Which means you have to specify that it's the `0` elements that should be compressed. You can do that by using `fill_value=0`, like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.SparseArray(a, fill_value=0), 'b':pd.SparseArray(b, fill_value=0)})
```

The result of `df.info()` is 1.4kb of memory usage in this case, quite a dramatic difference.

As to why it's initially bigger in your example than a normal "uncompressed" array, my guess is that it has to do with the compression data added on top of all the normal data that is still there (including zeros in your case). Anyway, that's just a guess

Additional reading in the docs would tell you that `0` is the default `fill_value` only in arrays of `data.dtype=int`, which yours weren't

Comment: Embarrassingly simple solution, thanks! I knew about the fill_value but wrongly assumed the default was 0, silly not to try. 
For interest, the memory difference between the two dataframes gets bigger with the size of the original df.